# How to sign up for questions on chosen subjects

Tags: support

How do I get notification of new questions on particular subjects (e.g. JavaFX or something) sent to me? I presume there is such a mechanism. Maybe someone can show me a link. Thanks.

I got a quick reply to this saying it was a duplicate. Went to the duplicate, didn't understand a thing. I got to the page saying "Favorite Tags". But I have absolutely no idea what to do next.

<sub>*I'm quite embarrassed asking this. But I have searched.*</sub>

Comment: TL;DR: it's not you, it's them. There is no easy way to get notifications for such thing, only a complicated workaround using the se.com filters. (And the sad/annoying part is that it was once super easy, they simply nuked it as part of some redesign.)